# Formatting data being written to a csv file with csv python 3.7

Tags: csv, formatting

I am trying to write the Barycenter positions of planets to a csv file. I am using skyfield api, csv and python 3.7. The position output is given as x y z coordinates. I want to have columns for the date/time which I have, columns for each of the x, y & z coordinates for each planet on the same row. I have tried 2 ways to achieve this, 1 gives the data in the columns how I want it but on separate rows and the other gives the header as I want but the coordinates for a planet are in are in a single column rather than 3 columns. I have looked at other formatting examples but none have resolved the issue I have.

#This is first attempt;#

```
`
from skyfield.api import utc
from skyfield.api import load
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date


planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
moon = planets['moon']
mercury = planets['mercury']
venus = planets['venus']
mars = planets['mars']
JUPITER_BARYCENTER = planets['JUPITER_BARYCENTER']
SATURN_BARYCENTER = planets['SATURN_BARYCENTER']
URANAS_BARYCENTER = planets['URANUS_BARYCENTER']
NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER = planets['NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER']
PLUTO_BARYCENTER = planets['PLUTO_BARYCENTER']

ts = load.timescale()


start_date = date(1986, 11, 8)
end_date = date(1986, 12, 31)
with open('BCRS positions-1.2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
         #date = datetime.strptime(single_date, "%Y/%m/%d")
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)                    
        t = ts.utc(single_date, 10, 30, 0)
        BCRS = ('Date', single_date, 
        'Sun-x','Sun-y','Sun-  z',sun.at(t).position.au,
        'Mercury-x','Mercury-y','Mercury-z', mercury.at(t).position.au,
        'Venus-x','Venus-y','Venus-z', venus.at(t).position.au,
        'Moon-x','Moon-y','Moon-z',moon.at(t).position.au,
        'Earth-x', 'Earth-y', 'Earth-z', earth.at(t).position.au,
        'Mars-x', 'Mars-y', 'Mars-z', mars.at(t).position.au,
        'Jupiter-x','Jupiter-y','Jupiter-z',   JUPITER_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au,
        'Saturn-x','Saturn-y','Saturn-z', SATURN_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au,
        'Uranas-x','Uranas-y','Uranas-z', URANAS_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au,
        'Neptune-x','Neptune-y','Neptune-z', NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au,
        'Pluto-x','Pluto-y','Pluto-z', PLUTO_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au)
        writer.writerow(BCRS)
```

csvfile.close()`

Output

Date,1986-11-08,Sun-x,Sun-y,Sun-z,[-0.0038418   0.0051725   0.00223502],Mercury-x,Mercury-y,Mercury-z,[0.30680392 0.12163008 0.03220969],Venus-x,Venus-y,Venus-z,[0.48875971 0.4985835  0.19301198],Moon-x,Moon-y,Moon-z,[0.6923354  0.65149371 0.28223558],Earth-x,Earth-y,Earth-z,[0.69095218 0.65328502 0.28325265],Mars-x,Mars-y,Mars-z,[1.38798446 0.094756   0.00565359],Jupiter-x,Jupiter-y,Jupiter-z,[ 4.93083814 -0.48155161 -0.32663981],Saturn-x,Saturn-y,Saturn-z,[-3.16415776 -8.82081358 -3.50690074],Uranas-x,Uranas-y,Uranas-z,[ -2.56470042 -17.41419317  -7.59061325],Neptune-x,Neptune-y,Neptune-z,[  2.85009934 -27.8321119  -11.46284476],Pluto-x,Pluto-y,Pluto-z,[-22.59654067 -19.26368339   0.79656139]

##This is the second attempt;##

```
from skyfield.api import utc
from skyfield.api import load
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date

# Sun, Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune and Pluto
planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
moon = planets['moon']
mercury = planets['mercury']
mars = planets['mars']
venus = planets['venus']
JUPITER_BARYCENTER = planets['JUPITER_BARYCENTER']
SATURN_BARYCENTER = planets['SATURN_BARYCENTER']
URANAS_BARYCENTER = planets['URANUS_BARYCENTER']
NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER = planets['NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER']
PLUTO_BARYCENTER = planets['PLUTO_BARYCENTER']
# Specfiy the date and time (UTC) for planets positions
# date/time format - t = ts.utc(yyyy, mm ,dd, hh, mm, ss)

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

ts = load.timescale()
start_date = datetime(1986, 11, 8, 10, 30, 0, tzinfo=utc)
end_date = datetime(1986, 12, 31, 10, 30, 0, tzinfo=utc)
with open('BCRS positions-test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(['Date', 'Sun-x', 'Sun-y', 'Sun-z', 'Mercury-x','Mercury-y','Mercury-z', 'Venus-x','Venus-y','Venus-z', 'Moon-x','Moon-y','Moon-z',
                           'Earth-x', 'Earth-y', 'Earth-z', 'Mars-x', 'Mars-y', 'Mars-z', 'Jupiter-x','Jupiter-y','Jupiter-z',
                           'Saturn-x','Saturn-y','Saturn-z', 'Uranas-x','Uranas-y','Uranas-z', 'Neptune-x','Neptune-y','UNeptune-z',
                           'Pluto-x','Pluto-y','Pluto-z'])
            for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
                single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
                #date = datetime.strptime(single_date, "%Y/%m/%d")
                t = ts.utc(single_date, 10, 30, 0)
                writer.writerow([single_date, sun.at(t).position.au, mercury.at(t).position.au, venus.at(t).position.au, moon.at(t).position.au,
                                    earth.at(t).position.au, mars.at(t).position.au, JUPITER_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au, SATURN_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au,
                                URANAS_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au, NEPTUNE_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au, PLUTO_BARYCENTER.at(t).position.au])

csvFile.close()
```

Output

Sun-x,Sun-y,Sun-z - I get this as a header in 3 columns
[-0.0038418   0.0051725   0.00223502] I get this in a single column below the header but needs to be in 3 columns one for each x, y, z position

###What I am trying to achieve is;###

Sun-x,Sun-y,Sun-z,Mercury-x,Mercury-y,Mercury-z,Venus-x,Venus-y,Venus-z
-0.003953380897142202,0.004828488778607356,0.0020912483521329586,-0.11600122254182059,-0.39948956059670143,-0.20224588140237967,-0.4899043811693688,0.47522226197221284,0.2444554690221239

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I need to achieve what I wanted.

```
from skyfield.api import wgs84
from skyfield.api import load
from skyfield.data import iers
from skyfield.api import utc
from pytz import timezone
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
from decimal import *

def weekly_it(start, finish):
    while finish > start:
    start = start + timedelta(weeks=1)
    yield start

start = datetime(1985, 6, 29, 9, 30, 15, tzinfo=utc)
finish = datetime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30, 15, tzinfo=utc)

fieldnames = ['Date', 'Sun-x', 'Sun-y', 'Sun-z', 'Mercury-x','Mercury-y','Mercury-z', 'Venus-x','Venus-y','Venus-z', 'Moon-x','Moon-y','Moon-z',
                       'Earth-x', 'Earth-y', 'Earth-z', 'Mars-x', 'Mars-y', 'Mars-z', 'Jupiter-x','Jupiter-y','Jupiter-z',
                       'Saturn-x','Saturn-y','Saturn-z', 'Uranas-x','Uranas-y','Uranas-z', 'Neptune-x','Neptune-y','UNeptune-z',
                       'Pluto-x','Pluto-y','Pluto-z']

with open('FileName.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:

    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for week in weekly_it(start, finish): 
        w = [week.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]

            astrometric = aveley.at(ts.utc(week)).observe(sun)
            r = w, astrometric.position.au
            flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(r))
            p = flatten_list
    
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=",")
            writer.writerows([p])
```

I Hope this helps someone with same issue